# Weird characters when I get Chinese via location.search

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to send Chinese characters through URL query string but they simply turn to some weird text format: `%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B3%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8` when I get them via `location.search`. How to get them correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I think your Chinese characters are being URL encoded.

Are you looking for the unescape function to decode them?

```
unescape("%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B3%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8")
```

Answer (score 0):

the text are url encoded, you should decode it first. Take a look at this page: [URLDecode](http://tool.chinaz.com/Tools/URLEncode.aspx) , select `gbk` to decode. There are corresponding functions in all popular languages to decode it.

Comment: What's the corresponding function in C++? Haskell? Erlang?